# Renaming a file doesn't rename the information in the content resolver

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3, android-contentresolver

I was loading audio files into my app using `contentResolver`, but, I renamed the audio file from `myaudio.mp3`(which it originally was) to `myNewAudio.mp3` but the `contentResolver` doesn't pick it up.

The information in my `listView` was being populated by fetching this particular attribute:

> MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE

But, renaming the audio file (which is only possible with the default file manager that android provides, i.e. the system file manager) doesn't seem to affect this information, and hence it's almost as if my `listView` is stale.

How can I refresh this information, if it is possible at all?

Comment: What is the situation after a reboot? Which Android version on device? Who created the file?

Comment: @blackapps ,  the file was downloaded, and I did reboot, and it seems to update after a reboot. Is there a way to force this before a reboot?

Comment: You did not tell who, how, when the file downloaded.

Comment: @blackapps , how is who, how , when necessary in this context? The file was a .mp3 media file, and it gets added to the content resolver after downloaded.

Comment: We would like to know if it was your app that did the download or another app or yet something else that could have placed that file there.

Comment: oh, I see, it was a media file downloaded from freesound .org ( I believe) from the default chrome browser on android

Comment: so, is there a way to refresh the contentResolver contents without a reboot?

Comment: If you used two different apps to download and delete a file then what does this have to do with your app? And we still do not know which app you used to delete on which Android version which is a pitty as we would like to blame that app.

Comment: but, I've never mentioned delete. The contentResolver is a class, the way it acts should be independent on the version of android, or atleast most features should be. It just gives us a Cursor to the type of media data required, and I just need a way to refresh that cursor

Comment: Ok, no delete but rename, sorry. All stays the same. And you dud not give the info asked for.